# Notation for ordered pairs of congruence classes

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation, direct-product

A homework question that I'm trying to solve is

> Determine the order of $(\mathbb{Z}_{12} \times \mathbb{Z}_4)/\langle ([3], [2]) \rangle$.

I recognize that that I need to find the order of the direct product $\mathbb{Z}_{12} \times \mathbb{Z}_4$, which is $\vert \mathbb{Z}_{12} \vert \cdot \vert \mathbb{Z}_4 \vert = 12 \cdot 4 = 48$, and that I also need $\vert \langle ([3], [2]) \rangle \vert$. The thing that I'm confused about is what $ ([3],[2]) $ means in this context. I know what $[3]$ and $[2]$ mean individually, that they're congruence classes, but I don't know what $([3], [2])$ means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{12} \times \mathbb{Z}_4$ are ordered pairs $(a,b)$ where $a \in \mathbb{Z}_{12}$ and $b \in \mathbb{Z}_4$. Does that clarify things? To calculate $\vert \langle ([3], [2]) \rangle \vert$ you'll also need to know that the the product of two ordered pairs is the ordered pair of the products in the components:
$$(a,b)(x,y) = (ax,by)$$

Comment: Like I said, I knew what the problem meant in regards to $\mathbb{Z}_{12} \times \mathbb{Z}_4$. I'm not just looking for how to calculate $\vert \langle ([3], [2]) \rangle \vert$, but I am looking for what $([3], [2])$ means. Is it meant to represent an ordered pair of congruence classes?

Comment: @AtomicNumberSix yes